# Conflicts between JSON-LD structured data objects?

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, json-ld, angular.js

Our site is an online clinic Management System that is developed with AngularJs.
I put structured data objects in JSON-LD format and just because our site is single page, I put general json-ld `(@type: Organization)` in layout, and dynamically add breadcrumb `(@type: BreadcrumbList)` and webpage `(@type: WebPage)` or article `(@type: NewsArticle)` data for each page.
Google Structured Data Testing Tool detect all my objects, and after a while They appeared in my Google Search Console.
The problem is, after I replaced the `(@type: Organization)` json-ld in layout, with another json-ld `(@type: WebApplication)`, google testing tools still show them, but all my other detected Structured Data in search console gone!

You can [check my data live here](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fboghrat.com%2Farticles%2F47).

Is there any conflicts between structured data objects?
For example: we cannot put any other structured data beside `(@type: WebApplication)`!

Answer (score 2):

your WebApplication snippet can't be recognized as those, because it isn't JSON-LD:
Your organization snippet begins with:
`<script type="application/ld+json">`

But your WebApplication snippet begins with:
`<script id="mainJsonLd" type="text/ng-template">`

After i changed it to `<script type="application/ld+json">` WebApplication is recognized like a charm:
[image]